# iPhone UITableView - animate all cells content at the same time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, cell, uitableview

I'm having problem with animating `cells` content at the same time. Once the cell is no longer visible (user scrolled the table), animation freezes. When the cell is visible again, animation continues.

All cells are precomputed in a separate method, and stored in `NSMutableArray`, so `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [_precomputedCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

The method, wich fills `_precomputedCells` array also fires all animations in each cell.

Any idea how can I assure, that all animations are being played no matter if cells are visible or not?

Comment: Why would you precompute your cells if you get lazy-loading for free from the table view?  You can verify the animations are in the correct state within the cells themselves, not within whatever view controller is managing that array.

Comment: I'm precomputing them to make sure, all animations will fire in the same time. I don't think they will all fire when I create them in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, since some of them are not visible.

Comment: Why not just call `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` on the array of `visibleCells` the TableView hands you to synchronize the animations?  You don't have to worry about visibility then, and you don't violate encapsulation by concerning the view controller with too much of the view.

Comment: Thanks, `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that `UITableView` removes invisible cells from the view hierarchy. That's why the animation stops.

An obvious solution would be to use `UIScrollView` instead of `UITableView`. It requires sligthly more work but nothing too complicated.

Another solution is to remove current cell animations and restart them when the cell appears, using some `UITableView` delegate method, e.g. `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.